# Is it possible to change a PayPal subscription after it has been created?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am a developer trying to determine if one can change the frequency of a PayPal subscription after the initial purchase/creation via API.  From what I’ve read of the developer API this is not possible, however I have been assured it is.

Can someone point out what I am missing and where I can find the developer documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can revise the subscription's plan and direct the customer to the resulting approve_url.

See the [integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#revise-subscription).